# Get paymentIntentSecret to Javascript with httppost

Tags: javascript, c#, stripe-payments

That's how my problem is when I need to httppost something. then i want to receive `subscription.LatestInvoice.PaymentIntent.ClientSecret` value over to my js file.

When I click pay then strip must specify an `subscription.LatestInvoice.PaymentIntent.ClientSecret` value for my js file.

But it never comes out.

However, Stripe informs me:

> Uncaught IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.handleCardPayment
>   intent secret: value should be a client secret of the form
>   ${id}*secret*${secret}. You specified: .

My httppost - Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("Members/AddMembership/{id}/{CompaniesId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddMembership(MembersView model)
    {
        try
        {

            //Here before that comes some strip code and everything else ...
            model.PiinVoice = subscription.LatestInvoice.PaymentIntent.ClientSecret;


            return View(model);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            TempData[TempDataClass.Error] = true;
            TempData[TempDataClass.ErrorMsg] = HelperText.ExceptionError + e.Message;
            return RedirectToAction("", "User");
        }
    }
```

I got the js code via Stripe which is on this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart#create-token).

My javascript here.

```
.... more here....
//I Need value from this one.
var paymentIntentSecret = document.getElementById('PiinVoice').value;  


// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {   
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.handleCardPayment(paymentIntentSecret).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Display error.message in your UI.
          // Inform the user if there was an error.
          var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
          errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.
          stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
});
.... more here...
```

What I would like to hear about it is possible to do so that `subscription.LatestInvoice.PaymentIntent.ClientSecret` is thrown into my PiinVoice. It is in relation to 3D Secure that it can be implemented.

Against if I run the old code before 3d. and paid and then went in and found the invoice id and thrown in at `var paymentIntentSecret = "xxxxxxx"` then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing `subscription.LatestInvoice.PaymentIntent.ClientSecret`in the backend code to investigate this? Since it seems to be null.

That could happen if you didn't [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects?lang=dotnet) that field when creating the subscription like the docs recommend. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#signup-4

```
var options = new SubscriptionCreateOptions
{
    CustomerId = customer.Id,
    Items = items,
    Expand = new List<string>() { "latest_invoice.payment_intent" }
};

var subscriptionServices = new SubscriptionService();
Subscription subscription = subscriptionServices.Create(options);
```